# Nginx proxy pass(rewrite/ redirect) to specific page on app server

Tags: nginx, proxy, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy, proxypass

Currently,

`https:// example.com` `proxy_pass` port `8080` via Nginx to : `https:// example.com/app/index.py`

Configuration file :

```
location  / {

                  proxy_ignore_client_abort on;
                  proxy_pass https://ip_address_app:8080/;
```

`/app/index.py` is default loading page on application server.

Now, I would like to rewrite/ redirect or proxy_pass to non-default loading page from :

```
https:// example.com -- > Nginx --> https:// example.com/app/xyz.py
```

I have tried `rewrite` , `proxy_redirect` and `proxy_pass` but it didnot work as expect.

I dont have permission to change anything on app server.

Please advise.

Thank you,

Comment: In your current configuration, how does `/` become `/app/index.py`? Does the application server take care of that? The solution may be as simple as adding `location = / { rewrite ^ /app/xyz.py last; }` to your existing Nginx configuration.

Comment: yes, but just checked your solution, ut got `Internal Server error`

Comment: Is there an error log entry?

Comment: `2018/11/08 17:07:31 [warn] 7743#7743: *584740 an upstream response is buffered to a temporary file /var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp/8/72/0000020728 while reading upstream, client: 115.79.137.201, server: example.com, request: "GET /app/getBackgroundImage.do HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://ip_address_app:8080/app/getBackgroundImage.do", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/app/index.py"`

Comment: That's a warning - are there no errors?

Comment: its contented of error.log , and here is access.log `115.79.137.201 - - [08/Nov/2018:17:07:06 +0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 193 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1" "-"
`

Comment: It looks like perhaps the 500 response if coming from the application server and not Nginx then.

Comment: if I access directly bypass Nginx, it works fine

Comment: Just combine `proxy_pass` for port maping and `rewrite` but still got 500

Comment: it's 500 error from Nginx

Comment: @RichardSmith any finds, appreciate ? I have tried but no luck.